# Electric field inside a box with conducting walls

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-fields, potential, boundary-conditions

A box made of 6 conducting plates as sides has vacuum inside. The plates are joined by an insulating layer, allowing for different plates to be set to different potentials. Initially, all sides are grounded. At a certain time $t_0$, one of the sides is connected to a DC generator set to $V_0$. What is the electric field/potential inside the box as a function of time and space?

Comment: Repost of https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/585111/electric-field-in-a-rectangular-box-with-time-varying-dirichlet-boundary-conditi

Comment: Yeah it's actually a more simple scenario to make it easier

Comment: Don't repost questions. If the answer is important to you, put a bounty on the question.

Answer (score 1):

We use Laplace's equation:

$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial z^2}\tag{1}$$

Assign the Cartesian coordinate system $(x,y,z)$ and place the plates on it. One of the plates (choose which one for convenience) will be at $V=V_0$ at $t=0$.

$(1)$ is a linear, second order $\text{PDE}$ which can often be solved using [separation of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables#Partial_differential_equations).

You have plenty *homogeneous* boundary conditions because all the other plates are at $V=0$, permanently because they are grounded.

So you will be looking for a function:
$$V(x,y,z,t)=X(x)Y(y)Z(z)\Theta(t)$$

As this is clearly a homework-style question this is a far as I should go towards solving.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This is actually not a homework question, though. Just as a follow up. In the lab situation, does connecting a plate to a certain voltage affect the vector potential A in any way? Or is the vector potential still constantly 0 throughout the whole process? I would expect it to be different from zero since I would expect EM waves to appear in the process. I' trying to calculate the electric field inside. Thanks!

Comment: Hiya. It's what's called a *homework style question* The potential will be $V_0$ at the time you connect the DC source to one of the plates (on that plate). The others stay at $V=0$. Hope this helps!

Comment: Electrical field waves will appear. Try not to worry too much about the "vector potential": Pascal's equation is about scalars...

Comment: @GastonMaffei if you’re concerned about transient magnetic fields, try Ampere’s Law once you have the time-dependent solution for $E=-\nabla V$.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. 

@Gert but I still need the solution for A to get E, no? I mean I have to add the time derivative for A. Are you saying the process is: use Lorenz gauge to solve for V using the wave equation with no sources  and the correct boundary conditions. Then  somehow use the Lorenz gauge condition to determine A?

Gilbert, isn't that equation missing the time derivative of A? I'm interested in the exact solution in time as well, not just the stationary solution where one of the plates is at $V_0$. I'm interested in feeding general potentials to the plates

Comment: *I'm interested in feeding general potentials to the plates –* So time-dependent BCs? That'll be very challenging, analytically speaking.

Comment: Also, several of the question you're posing here (in the comment section) weren't part of the OP, that makes it very hard for members to answer...

Comment: @Gert yes, time-dependent BCs. That's why I said that at a certain point in time the plate is set at $V_0$, the simplest time dependent BC (as opposed to the static solution). As for your other comment, not really, right? I did specify I was wondering how to calculate E inside the box at all times and the setup I described involved time dependent BCs

Comment: Best start 'simple' methinks, then try adding more complexity. Start with a static $V_0$ and all other potentials at $0$ and see what that gets you for $V(x,y,z,t)$...

Comment: I mean, I already have the solution in the static case (t dependence is irrelevant) using separation of variables. It's the dynamic case that eludes me, hence the post.

Comment: Simply use sep. of variables on the case where $\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} \neq 0$... As I stated in the answer.